# How to simulate click on a display:none on hover image (how to listen for any mouse click in a browser)

Tags: javascript, html, css

On [a website (find it by the link)](http://bassfunk.herokuapp.com/) I have links with [images in footer (screenshot)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7isg66bsbhz4txg/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202014-12-11%2015.30.43.png?dl=0)

I have found a great glitch effect in a footer icons which I want to use. It chages images randomly if code looks like that:

```
<footer class="footer text-center">
       <a target="_blank" href="http://link1.com"><img src="f2.jpg"></a>
       <a href="http://link2.com"><img src="f3.jpg"></a>
       <a target="_blank" href="http://link3.com"><img src="f1.jpg"></a>
       <a target="_blank" href="http://link4.com"><img src="f5.jpg"></a>
        <a target="_blank" href="http://link5.com"><img src="bc.png"></a>
        <a href="mailto:http://link6.com@gmail.com"><img src="mail.jpg"></a>

 </footer>
```

and simple style

```
.footer img:hover {
    display:none;
}
```

But in that scenario click while hovering on of the image footers gives no result.

I've tried to use javascript:

```
var a_href
$("footer a").on("mousemove", function() {
  a_href = $(this).attr('href');
  console.log(a_href);

});

$(document).click(function(){
  console.log("!!!!!!!!!!!");
  console.log(a_href);
  window.open(a_href,'_blank');
});
```

Idea was to save the last hovered link and then emulate the click on it by clicking any other element. But that method works only if I click anywhere ELSE than a space over the glitchy icons. Same with `$('body').click`, `$('.footer').click`. 
I've tried to overlay footer with other div on which i'd be putting `.click` but then `display:none` on `hover` doesn't work.

**Here is a [jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/yssdjr17/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/yssdjr17/1/)**

What should I do? Thank you.

**UPD**
If we use something instead of a `display:none` we loose the cool glitch effect that way. We loved how randomly elements collapsed and that user might click on one of the elements, but never sure on which one. Some sort of a minigame for him.

**Is there a way to listen for a mouseclick, in browser, no matter on what element?**

Comment: Why do you want to hide the hovered element?

Comment: it looks cool and glitchy :-)

Comment: Also, the images don't change, it's just that the one hovered gets virtually removed and the next ones slide over, just as expected. I don't really see what your problem is.

Comment: To make it more obvious, change `display:none` to `visibility:hidden` to keep the element dimensions, you will see

Comment: But we loose the cool glitch effect that way. We loved how randomly elements collapsed and that user might click on one of the elements, but never sure on wich one. Some sort of a minigame for him.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `display: none`, use `visibility: hidden` instead. This way the element will still be there, just not visible.

```css
.footer img:hover {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yssdjr17/2/).

Comment: But we loose the cool glitch effect that way. We loved how randomly elements collapsed and that user might click on one of the elements, but never sure on wich one. Some sort of a minigame for him.

Answer (score 0):

The effect makes it look broken.
You can't fire the click event from anything hidden or not displayed.

Instead try:

```
<div id="awesomelink" onclick="openawesomewindow('http://link1.com');"></div>

#awesomelink
{
 height:60px;
 width:60px;
 background-image:url('f1.jpg');
}
#awesomelink:hover
{
 background-image:url('awesomecrazyanimated.gif');
}
```

It's how I'd do it and you'll get a more consistant result across different browsers.
Also the menu of icons won't be shortened by one element making savvy surfers afraid to click.

Comment: But we loose the cool glitch effect that way. We loved how randomly elements collapsed and that user might click on one of the elements, but never sure on wich one. Some sort of a minigame for him. It should look broken for the glitch aesthetics.

Comment: Okay, do the thing Mr Donnelly posted.